# Is there exists linear algebra basis for $L^2[0,1]$ such that every element of it has length one and every two different element of it is orthogonal?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

We know by using axiom of choice every vector space over a division ring ( consequently any field ) has a basis like **$\mathbb E$** in the meaning of linear algebra **( $\mathbb E$ is linear independent set and the set of all finite linear combination of elements of $\mathbb E$ is entire space).** In infinite dimensional case this basis is not appropriate for analysis and analytical purposes because this basis has been obtained from axiom of choice and it is not constructive , so a new concept of basis has been defined as follow:

Suppose we have an infinite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb C$ which has a norm, now we say $\mathbb M$ is **basis (in new definition )** when $\mathbb M$ is linear independent set and the set of all infinite linear combination of elements of $\mathbb M$ is dense ( respect to norm ). So every basis in the meaning of linear algebra is a basis in new definition.

Consider Hilbert space $L^2[0,1]$ with usual inner product, we know it has basis respect to both two definition above. and even it has a basis in new definition such that norm of every element of it is one and every two different element of it is orthogonal ( respect to inner product ) .

Now I think $L^2[0,1]$ hasn't a basis in the meaning of linear algebra such that norm of every element of it is one and every two different element of it is orthogonal ( respect to inner product ).

Is this true ?

Comment: Yes, it's true. An orthonormal system in $L^2[0,1]$ is (at most) countable, but a Hamel basis (basis in the linear algebra sense) is uncountable (has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, more precisely).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such basis exists.

What you call a "linear algebra basis" is more commonly called a Hamel basis in this setting.  If $H$ is any infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, then it does not have a Hamel basis whose elements are pairwise orthogonal.

Let $B \subset H$ be an infinite set whose elements are pairwise orthogonal; we will show $B$ does not span $H$.  Without loss of generality, assume $0 \notin B$.  Choose countably many elements $x_1, x_2, \dots$ from $B$ and let $$x = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i} \frac{x_i}{\|x_i\|}.$$ (It is a standard exercise to use completeness to show the series converges in $H$.)  Now let $\{y_1, \dots, y_n\}$ be any finite subset of $B$.  Choose one of the $x_i$ that is not in $\{y_1, \dots, y_n\}$.  Then $x_i$ is orthogonal to any finite linear combination of the $y_j$, but using the continuity of the inner product, $\langle x, x_i \rangle = \frac{\|x_i\|}{i} \ne 0$.  Hence $x$ is not a finite linear combination of $y_1, \dots, y_n$.  But $y_1, \dots, y_n$ were arbitrary, so $x$ is not in the linear span of $B$.